# Gradle is stuck on compiling Android Unit Tests task

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I am running into an issue where Gradle never completes the compile unit tests task for my Android app, `:app:compileMainAppDebugUnitTestKotlin`. Also, the failing task is only for the branch of code I'm working on, a merge of two branches. Independently, both branches complete the task quickly (1 minute or less). Although it fails to compile unit tests, the merged branch compiles and builds the app successfully.

Here are the logs from the compile unit tests command :

```
 ./gradlew :app:compileMainAppDebugUnitTestKotlin
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [8m 42s]
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> :app:compileMainAppDebugUnitTestKotlin
> IDLE
```

Attempted solutions:

1. Comment out all test classes where either branch modified tests
2. Use `-d` and `-i` Gradle log levels to look for issues
3. Ensure both branches supported the merged branch completed the `:app:compileMainAppDebugUnitTestKotlin` successfully

Gradle version: 6.5, Kotlin version: 1.3.72, Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Please let me know if you have any ideas or need additional info.